# linux-watch command: show time remaining

Tags: python, linux, watch

I recently posted this thread: [run a python script everytime the computer wakes up from hibernation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852683/run-a-python-script-everytime-the-computer-wakes-up-from-hibernation)

I am thinking of an alternative for the countdown, which would be to simply show on the console the time remaining till the command is ran again.

For example with this script

```
import os
os.system("watch -n 50 COMMAND")
```

the console shows Every 50 seconds run: COMMAND
So do you know of a way to show the actual state of this 50 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way unless the `COMMAND` creates some information (e. g. a timestamp after its execution or similar).  The reason for this is simple:  The `watch` simple enters a `nanosleep()` system call to wait for the 50 seconds.  (You can find this out using `strace`.)  This `nanosleep()` does nothing else but wait for 50 seconds.  It does not provide any information anywhere on how long the sleep already has been going on or how long it still will take.  That information is buried deep inside the kernel who will, eventually, wake up the process again.

So, your only way is making the `COMMAND` render that information, e. g. by letting it touch a timestamp file (e. g. `touch /tmp/COMMAND.timestamp`) whose time then can be used to determine indirectly when the next sleep will probably be finished.

Answer (score 0):

Directly? no, watch doesn't expose that.
Instead you have to make watch run more frequently and handle the check youself, like this:

```
import os
os.system("watch -n 1 'let \"x = $(date +%s)%50\";echo $x; if [ $x -eq 0 ]; then COMMAND ; fi'")
```

You will probably want to format the `echo $x` to your taste.